# Use S3 bucket as maven repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

how to use AWS API gateway to download jar file in order to use as a maven repo. Currently having a problem with resolving response type to binary. Used headers and content types, downloading jar file getting corrupted.
basically, we need to call rest API using GET with authentication token in the header, when the header is validated by lambda function as "authorizer" request need to proxy to S3 bucket and get the appropriate object (jar file)

Comment: Why do you want to use API Gateway / Lambda versus something like the [Spring S3 wagon](https://github.com/spring-projects/aws-maven)? And why not use an actual repository manager?

Comment: Need to achieve high availability and authenticate user even pulling dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-content-encodings-examples-image-s3.html) to implement a basic proxy API gateway and S3 and add 'binary/octet-stream' to Binary Media Types under API settings. Finally, create authorizer with custom token authentication pass-through header (use your own logic)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-content-encodings-examples-image-s3.html